# Group by Time(Only hrs part) in linq

Tags: c#, linq, time, datatable

I have a datatable that has following columns

```
CallTime   CallType

15:45:00    Voice
15:30:54    Voice
00:12:14    SMS
01:13:47    Voice
05:48:23    SMS
12:00:47    Voice
```

Now what i want Using Linq Result Like This

```
Hrs   Count
00    1
01    1
05    1
12    1
15    2
```

I have tried Group by using Linq, But not getting it right.

I used the following code

```
   var groupQuery = from table in Foundrows.AsEnumerable()
                         group table by table["Call Time"] into groupedTable
                         select new
                         {
                             CallTime = groupedTable.Key,
                             CallCount = groupedTable.Count()
                         };
```

Comment: What is the type of `CallTime` is it TimeSpan ? or string

Comment: Is CallTime a DateTime field? If so, do you want to group by hour or by date+hour?

Comment: It is string but can be parsed succesfully as time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var groupQuery = from r in Foundrows.AsEnumerable()
                 group r by r.Field<TimeSpan>("CallTime").Hours into g
                 select new {
                    Hrs = g.Key,
                    CallCount = g.Count()
                 };
```

If your column of `string` type then just parse it's value into `TimeSpan`:

```
var groupQuery = from r in Foundrows.AsEnumerable()
                 let time = TimeSpan.Parse(r.Field<string>("CallTime"))
                 group r by time.Hours into g
                 select new {
                    Hrs = g.Key,
                    CallCount = g.Count()
                 };
```

---

```
Foundrows.AsEnumerable()
         .Select(r => {
             TimeSpan time;
             return new {
                Row = r,
                Time = TimeSpan.TryParse(r.Field<string>("CallTime"), out time) ?
                       time : (TimeSpan?)null
             };
         })
         .Where(x => x.Time.HasValue)
         .GroupBy(x => x.Time.Value.Hours)
         .Select(g => new {
             Hrs = g.Key,
             CallCount = g.Count()
         });
```

Or you can use `TryParse` which will return nullable `TimeSpan` method like this:

```
public static TimeSpan? TryParse(string s)
{
    TimeSpan time;
    if (TimeSpan.TryParse(s, out time))
       return time;

    return null;
}
```

And use it in original query:

```
var groupQuery = from r in Foundrows.AsEnumerable()
                 let time = TryParse(r.Field<string>("CallTime"))
                 where time.HasValue
                 group r by time.Value.Hours into g
                 select new {
                    Hrs = g.Key,
                    CallCount = g.Count()
                 };
```

Comment: If i wanna use TryParse instead of Parse, What changes would i need to make in code

Comment: Also need to Sort the result order by hrs in the same linq query

Comment: @RajeevKumar if you have valid time values, then all should work as is. But if you don't, then hold on, I'll add `TryParase` in a minute

Comment: @RajeevKumar: Edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16030754/284240) to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to group by hour and the field "Call Time" is a `DateTime` field:

```
var groupQuery = from row in Foundrows.AsEnumerable()
                 let hour = row.Field<DateTime>("Call Time").Hour 
                 group row by hour into hourGroup
                 select new {
                    CallHour = hourGroup.Key,
                    CallCount = hourGroup.Count()
                 };
```

If you want to group by the combination of the `Date` + `Hour`:

```
var groupQuery = from row in Foundrows.AsEnumerable()
                 let date = row.Field<DateTime>("Call Time")
                 let hour = date.Hour
                 group row by new{ date, hour } into dateHourGroup
                 select new {
                     CallDate = dateHourGroup.Key.date,
                     CallHour = dateHourGroup.Key.hour,
                     CallCount = dateHourGroup.Count()
                 };
```

**Edit**: If it's actually a `TimeSpan` (as it seems to be), use lazyberezovsky's approach :)

> Your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16030676/284240): If i wanna use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`, What
>   changes would i need to make in code?

I would recommend to create an extension which allows to return a `Nullable<TimeSpan>`, then you can check if `HasValue==true`:

```
public static TimeSpan? TryGetTimeSpan(this string tsString, string format = null)
{
    TimeSpan ts;
    bool success;
    if (format == null)
        success = TimeSpan.TryParse(tsString, out ts);
    else
        success = TimeSpan.TryParseExact(tsString, format, null, TimeSpanStyles.None, out ts);
    return success ? (TimeSpan?)ts : (TimeSpan?)null;
}
```

Now this query works efficiently and don't uses undocumented side-efects (as a local `TimeSpan` variable that you use for `TimeSpan.TryParse` in the query):

```
var groupQuery = from r in Foundrows.AsEnumerable()
                 let time = r.Field<string>("CallTime").TryGetTimeSpan()
                 where time.HasValue
                 group r by time.Value.Hours into g
                 select new
                 {
                     Hrs = g.Key,
                     CallCount = g.Count()
                 };
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.. u really makes it easy